# DataTrigger based on value of cell in DataGrid bound to DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to change the background of the row in my **DataGrid** based on the current value of one of the cells. My research has led me to the conclusion that you can do this with a **DataTrigger** but I can't seem to write a binding expression that won't error.

My XAML for the section is as follows:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TodaysBets}" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" TextBlock.FontSize="14" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Matched}" Value="false"> //This binding expression failing
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       ......DataGridColumn Definitions here all bound to "TodaysBets"
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The matched column is a boolean and it keeps throwing out binding errors like cannot find property **Matched** on object **DataRowView**. Can anyone help I have tried everything??

The error it is throwing out is this:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Matched' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=4932563)'. BindingExpression:Path=Matched; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=4932563); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')`

Comment: Solution: create a proper strongly typed data model with proper properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged` and forget the age-old, ugly, untyped, magic-string based DataTable stuff.

Comment: @HighCore Can you elaborate? I am fairly new to WPF and thought I was going about things the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution to this. All I had to do was change my binding expression to:

```
Binding="{Binding Row.Matched}"
```

Because the binding was selecting the DataRowView so I had to make the binding expression select the underlying DataRow before I could bind to the correct property.